# Delphi - How to create a stacked bar series during runtime?

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-10.3-rio

I would like to create 2 series that stack upon each other using the Teechart series in Delphi during runtime.
Essentially I want to have 2 series, each with 2 entries, or data points, and the corresponding data points, i.o.w series1 datapoint1 and series 2 datapoint 1, should stack upon each other to form a single
bar.

I have tried to look for a procedure or property to change to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal example:

```
var
  S1, S2: TBarSeries;
begin
  S1 := TBarSeries(Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries));
  S2 := TBarSeries(Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries));
  S1.MultiBar := mbStacked;
  S2.MultiBar := mbStacked;
  //S1.StackGroup := 0;
  //S2.StackGroup := 0;  //same group if few groups will be used
  S1.Add(3);
  S1.Add(1);
  S2.Add(2);
  S2.Add(4);
```